# Calling javascript function when page loaded without onclick

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have an footer.php file that have javascript code and functions. I use this footer.php file for all of my pages. When clicking buttons I use

```
onclick="MyFunc()"
```

but in some pages I need to call MyFunc without onclick, just when page loaded. I can not use "body onload" function because the  tag is in header.php file that all pages is using it. I have triend to put

```
<script Language="JavaScript">
window.onload=MyFunc; 
</script>
```

in my php file and

```
<script Language="JavaScript">
function MyFunc(){
alert('hello');
}
</script>
```

in the footer.php but with no luck.

Comment: if you dont have problem with jquery, then you can use `$('document').load(/*your function*/)`.

Comment: why you are not using jquery ?? $('document').ready()

Comment: You could use jquery library and then `$(window).load(function () {
  MyFunc(); 
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"but in some pages I need to call MyFunc without onclick"*

What I understand from your question is:

- You want to fire `MyFunc` on a few pages
- All pages include `footer.php` (at the end, I assume).
- `MyFunc` is already present

If that's right, you'll have to trigger this event somehow only on the pages that you want it to fire. This can be done two ways.

#### Add a small snippet to the automatically firing pages

```
window.addEventListener('load', MyFunc, false);
```

This code will add the `MyFunc` function to the array that will be fired when the page is laded. *Remember: `window.onload` and this will fire **after** all images have been loaded*.

#### Trigger `MyFunc` automatically

I don't know what the difference between those pages is, but this could be done by firing the function when the page is loaded, just like the snippet I showed above, and just before this is done you check for a trigger. For example, if your page where it fires has an element with a specific class `test`, simply check if it exists (`document.getElementsByClassName('test').length > 0`) and then fire `MyFunc`.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As stated you could use `window.onload` or you could attach the event to DOM load

```
<body onload="MyFunc()"></body>
```

Comment: Is that comment aimed at me?

Comment: I can not use "body onload" function because the tag is in header.php I MENTIONED THIS!!!

Comment: @DanM No need to get angry. He clearly stated `window.onload` which can be called from everywhere on your page.

Comment: My bad, didn't fully read the question. Still no need to get angry like that. Anyway if you don't want to use jQuery as mentioned, you could use `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded, MyFunc);`

Comment: Sorry for getting angry, but after I posted my question and got like 5 answers from people that did not read fully my question, just guised the answer. Sorry again

Comment: @DanM They actually did answer your question _AND_ mentioned the `<body load="MyFunc">` method, as it isn't clear what exactly it is you need.

Answer (score 0):

as I know the language attribute is obsolete
try to use `<script type="text/javascript">` instead of `<script Language="JavaScript">`

EDIT: put a sample to here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C2FGS/)

Comment: without the rendered html source I think we stucked, would you share it with us on jsfiddle maybe?

Answer (score 0):

if its in the footer (end of the page) you  can simply enter this code where you need

```
<script>
    MyFunc()
</script>
```

this will call the function